# Can't pip install psutil (Arch)

Tags: python, pip, psutil

I can't find out what the exact problem with the install of psutil is, all errors lead me to very old threads with different versions, or other distros. Mostly missing headers which are included.

```
$ pip install psutil
    Collecting psutil
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/ca/5b8c1fe032a458c2c4bcbe509d1401dca9dda35c7fc46b36bb81c2834740/psutil-5.6.3.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: psutil
      Building wheel for psutil (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /opt/anaconda/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-xsbcm34z --python-tag cp37                                                                                                                                                                                                      
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/                                                                                                                                                                  
      Complete output (61 lines):                                                                                                                                                                                  
      running bdist_wheel                                                                                                                                                                                          
      running build                                                                                                                                                                                                
      running build_py                                                                                                                                                                                             
      creating build                                                                                                                                                                                               
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7                                                                                                                                                                          
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                                   
      copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                            
      copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                               
      copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                               
      copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                                             
      copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                               
      copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
      copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
      copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                 
      copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                         
      copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
      copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                            
      copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                          
      copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
      copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
      copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                    
      copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
      copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
      running build_ext                                                                                                                                                                                            
      building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension                                                                                                                                                                    
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7                                                                                                                                                                         
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                                  
      gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o                                                                                                            
      gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o                                                                                                              
      psutil/_psutil_posix.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_flags':                                                                                                                                                   
      psutil/_psutil_posix.c:415:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]                                                                                          
        415 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));                                                                                                                                           
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                            
      psutil/_psutil_posix.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_mtu':                                                                                                                                                     
      psutil/_psutil_posix.c:376:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]                                                                                          
        376 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));                                                                                                                                           
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                            
      gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_linux.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o                                                                                                              
      psutil/_psutil_linux.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_duplex_speed':                                                                                                                                            
      psutil/_psutil_linux.c:539:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]                                                                                          
        539 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));                                                                                                                                           
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                            
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -L/opt/anaconda/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/anaconda/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so                                      
      /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info                                                        
      /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info                                                        
      /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info                                                        
      /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info                                                        
      build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized                                                                                                         
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                                                                                                                   
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1                                                                                                                                                               
      ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                     
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
      Running setup.py clean for psutil
    Failed to build psutil
    ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.13.1 which is incompatible.
    ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 has requirement pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqtwebengine 5.13.1 which is incompatible.
    Installing collected packages: psutil
        Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /opt/anaconda/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-g9lzx155/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile   
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/                                                                                                                                                                
        Complete output (61 lines):                                                                                                                                                                                
        running install                                                                                                                                                                                            
        running build                                                                                                                                                                                              
        running build_py                                                                                                                                                                                           
        creating build                                                                                                                                                                                             
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7                                                                                                                                                                        
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                                 
        copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                          
        copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                             
        copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                             
        copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                            
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                                           
        copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                             
        copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                            
        copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
        copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                               
        copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                       
        copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                              
        copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                          
        copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                        
        copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
        copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
        copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                  
        copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
        copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                
        running build_ext                                                                                                                                                                                          
        building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension                                                                                                                                                                  
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7                                                                                                                                                                       
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil                                                                                                                                                                
        gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o                                                                                                          
        gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o                                                                                                            
        psutil/_psutil_posix.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_flags':                                                                                                                                                 
        psutil/_psutil_posix.c:415:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]                                                                                        
          415 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));                                                                                                                                         
              |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                          
        psutil/_psutil_posix.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_mtu':
        psutil/_psutil_posix.c:376:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
          376 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
              |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        gcc -pthread -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/opt/anaconda/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_linux.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o
        psutil/_psutil_linux.c: In function 'psutil_net_if_duplex_speed':
        psutil/_psutil_linux.c:539:5: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
          539 |     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, nic_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
              |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        gcc -pthread -shared -B /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat -L/opt/anaconda/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/anaconda/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
        /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
        /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
        /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
        build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
        collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/anaconda/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ay_2kk3f/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-g9lzx155/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `anaconda`, so why not `conda install -c conda-forge psutil `?

Comment: Code formatting can also be done by wrapping the code with ``` ... ``` (see my edit)

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm trying to install the DeepLabCut conda env. using conda-forge works for psutil, but I'd like to solve the error nonetheless as my env is also not created correctly with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have not installed `python3.7-dev`
You can install it using `pip3 install python3.7-dev`
Before that you can upgrade pip using `pip install -U pip`